# Adding a checkbox to a edittext/textview?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, spannablestring

I have an application that needs a rich text editor.

I intend to implement this using spannables or assigning an html code as the text of the textview.

Can I add a checkbox in the same way?

Comment: some example images will be helpful.

Comment: You want to set text for checkbox or what?

Comment: If any answer helped you consider to upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show html in `TextView` you should first convert in to `Spanned` using `Html.fromHtml()`. But only a small HTML tag subset can be used in this method because spannables are used for styling text. If you want to add checkbox then you should do this outside of `TextView`.

Comment: Is <input type="checkbox" /> not available in the allowed list?

Comment: No, only `a, b, big, blockquote, br, cite, dfn, div, em, font, i, img, p, small, strong, sub, sup, tt, u` tags. For `img` tag you have to include `ImageGetter`. More information http://daniel-codes.blogspot.ru/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as `CheckBox` extended from `TextView` you can use `setText` method with you `Spannable`.

For example:

```
    SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(poweredBy + " " + company);
    int start = poweredBy.length();
    int end = spannableStringBuilder.length();
    spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(companyColor), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    checkbox.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```

Comment: what does "CheckBox extended from TextView" mean?

Comment: @user2495720 According to CheckBox class hierarchy: CheckBox -> CompoundButton -> Button -> TextView. setText method is a method implemented in TextView, which mean that this functionality is also works in CheckBox